# Android BroadcastReceiver not stopping Camera Intent action

Tags: android

I am trying to 'block' the Camera action while my application is active. The *onReceive* method is being executed on the BroadcastReceiver, but by the LogCat it seems to be doing so after the Intent has already been executed.

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:debuggable="true"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <receiver android:name="com.receiver.CameraReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

**com.receiver.CameraReceiver**

```
package com.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class CameraReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(this.toString(), "Suck It Android!");
        abortBroadcast();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.receiver.CameraReceiver";
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
12-03 14:47:41.171: INFO/ActivityManager(981): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.google.android.camera/com.android.camera.Camera }
12-03 14:47:41.288: INFO/WindowManager(981): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
12-03 14:47:41.304: INFO/ActivityManager(981): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/4 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=2/2 orien=2 layout=34 uiMode=17 seq=30}
12-03 14:47:41.811: DEBUG/dalvikvm(981): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8025 objects / 388808 bytes in 208ms
12-03 14:47:41.999: DEBUG/AlarmManagerService(981): Kernel timezone updated to 300 minutes west of GMT
12-03 14:47:42.288: INFO/[com.specialed.receiver.CameraReceiver](13152): Suck It Android!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was able to do it by adding

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to my intent fiter, so it looks like:

```
<receiver android:name="com.receiver.CameraReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and this seems to be working, can anybody comment to if this or the `android:priority` is the proper way.

Also, if I can stop the 'Vibrate' that happens on button press that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly whether i'm completely wrong about this, but it's my understanding, that a BroadcastReceiver won't stop another activity but is being executed parallely.

Edit: I found a thread in the google android dev group that might help you:
[click](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/b068dfe35ebbb5fe/88f934107dd3ea95?lnk=gst&q=camera+button#88f934107dd3ea95)

The essence:
Set high priority of your Receiver to a high value, so Android chooses your app to start first when the camera button is pressed.

`<intent-filter android:priority=*"10000"*>`

And first line of your `onReceive()`: `abortBroadcast();`